# continue transfer data of start button after releasing in MVC-python

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller

in model-view-controller, i want communication between them still processing when i pressed start button and released it. the data is continue to be transferred form view to controller , model forth and back as function assigned for start button until i press stop.

such as:
function A:
n=1
def A(n):
pub.sendMessage("calculate N +1")

Controller listens that request from view then send to model to do, the model calculates and send back to view to display, then n=n+1 and view will send another request. it happens until i press stop button.
i can use the for loop with global variance but in that case, i can't use other function because it just go only the loop.